# mock call returns an empty list

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-decorators

I am writing a unittest for a model. The call returns an empty list and I am not sure how can I debug what's going wrong.
Here's my code:

```
    @patch('app.models.client.post')
    def test_something(self, mock):
       
        method_mock.return_value = None
        payloads = [json.loads(call[2]['data']) for call in mock.mock_calls]
        
        # do something else

        self.assertEquals('stuff', payloads[0]['x']['y'])
```

I notice that `mock.mock_calls` returns `[]` and hence, the error `list index out of range` in assert
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you calling a function that hits your app.models.client.post function? If not, mock_calls will be empty. mock_calls is a list of `Call` objects for every time the mock has been called, so it makes sense it is empty if you setup your mock, and then immediately ask for how it has been called.

Comment: client is basically `client = requests.Session()` in models.py. That's all the usage so far

Answer (score 1):

In your code, between the instantiation of the mock (your patch decorator) and your first call of `mock.mock_call`, I do not see any logic that would end up calling `app.models.client.post`.

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>> m = Mock()
>>> m.mock_calls  # mock_calls is empty, we've never called the mock ex: m('something')
[]
>>> m('a')  # we call it
<Mock name='mock()' id='4342272064'>
>>> m.mock_calls  # mock_calls is populated with the arguments of the call
[call('a')]
```

You'll have to trigger the code that calls `client.post` in `app.models`. Perhaps by using `RequestFactory`?

Comment: @twingo did this help?